# Extension of two-generated ideals in ring extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be a subring of a commutative ring $R$ and $a,b,c,d$ are all in $S$. If ideals $(a,b) = (c,d)$ in R, does $(a, b) = (c,d)$ still hold in $S$? If not, what would be a necessary condition on $R$ or $S$ for the statement to hold true?

Comment: No. For example, let $R = \mathbb{Q}, S = \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $S\subset R$ is faithfully flat or $S$ is a direct summand of $R$ (considered as $S$-module), then $IR\cap S=I$ for any ideal $I\subset S$.